Is the class of all Hamiltonian graphs axiomatizable in second-order logic?
Is the class of all Hamiltonian graphs axiomatizable in second-order logic?
Definitions:

Hamiltonian graph is a graph s.t. there exists a cycle that goes exactly once through all vertices
a class is axiomatizable in second-order logic if there is a set of second-order sentences $T$ s.t. (using standard semantics) $G\models T \iff G\text{ "is Hamiltonian"}$

To my knowledge, the property of "being Hamiltonian graph" is not translatable into some nice set of conditions (as opposed to e.g. Eulerian graph). So I was wondering whether it is even characterizable in second-order. I suppose that first-order is out of question due to compactness theorem.

Isn't the definition of Hamiltonian graph manifestly second-order? "There exists a set $C$ of pairs of vertices such that..."

@AlexKruckman oh, I see. Then there should be no problem, thanks.
